Vue 3 Custom Components to lib build
I connect my components like this:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import { ComponentLibrary } from '@frontend-ui/vue-ui/dist/plugin'

createApp(App).use(ComponentLibrary).mount('#app')

vite.config.ts:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.includes('-')
        }
      }
    }),
    vueJsx()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
      name: 'auth-service',
      fileName: 'auth-service'
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

How can I register these global components when building into a library?
I need the final assembly to include components from the library

Can you clarify what is the problem? Global components are supposed to be registered by a plugin, supposedly ComponentLibrary. What is the current implementation?

In dev development mode, a plugin with global components is added like this:
import { ComponentLibrary } from '@frontend-ui/vue-ui/dist/plugin'
createApp(App).use(ComponentLibrary).mount('#app')

But when I try to build components as a library, the plugin is not registered and these global components are not included in the assembly
I need to add a plugin when building to a library, but I haven't found how to do it

"build components" - which ones? The components from @frontend-ui/vue-ui/dist/plugin should have already been built at this point

My library uses components from another library - @frontend-ui/vue-ui/dist/plugin, in dev mode they are there, but not in build mode

This createApp(App).use(ComponentLibrary) doesn't look like lib code, this is app code. Generally there's no such problem associated with using someone else's components in your project, so it's very specific to your case, it's unclear what happens on your side. How exactly do you determine they are "not there"? Do you get errors/warnings or are there other clues? What are the actions to reproduce on your side? The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and lacks details, so it doesn't seem possible to reproduce it by someone else

In case what you build is really a library that's supposed to be used in other projects, a third-party library (@frontend-ui/vue-ui) is usually added to project dependencies and Vite external, similarly to vue. Probably that's what's missing here
